# How do I set a path permanently?

Tags: bash, environment-variables

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to add a directory to my path?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60218/how-to-add-a-directory-to-my-path)

I am trying to install the play framework permanently.
http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.2/Installing

```
export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/play20
```

This works fine, but after i close my command line, i have to reinstall it. 
Is there a permanent solution?