# Cannot run a linux binary

Tags: 12.10, binary

I was trying to run a linux binary from this site:

http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/research/affine/descriptors.html#binaries

specifically, the "compute_descriptors.ln"

However, the terminal only responded with `command not found`.  The extension also looks very uncommon.

I am running Ubuntu 12.10.

Comment: what command did you type? could you copy/paste the exact command and the exact repsonse?

Comment: I downloaded the .gz file, extract it. then type "compute_descriptors.ln" in a terminal as indicated in the webpage mentioned.

Comment: I did change my path correctly

Comment: Sorry, just noticed typo in my question. the responds was "command not found"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably typed

```
$ compute_descriptors.ln
```

but you need to do

```
$ ./compute_descriptors.ln
```

(notice the leading `./`, that is also mentioned on the site you linked)
The command isn't known "globally" (in your path) so you must specify that the command is in fact in this directory.

You could also need to do a `chmod +x`, but i'd just try the `./` prepending first.

Comment: hi, thanks. actually, I made both mistakes. Just another questions: how do we add a folder to the "globally" known path. I assume that it is similar to the PATH environment variable in Windows?

Comment: You can set your path environment like you can read here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/170222/how-do-i-set-a-path-permanently .

Answer (score 1):

I think you missed some steps (`chmod +x` maybe?). Works for me:

```
$ wget http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/[...]/compute_descriptors.ln.gz                
[...]
2012-12-12 11:55:36 (1.55 MB/s) - `compute_descriptors.ln.gz' saved [3222607/3222607]                                            

$ gunzip compute_descriptors.ln.gz                                                                             
$ chmod +x compute_descriptors.ln 
$ ./compute_descriptors.ln 
Interest point descriptors implemented by Krystian.Mikolajczyk@inrialpes.fr                                                      
at INRIA Rhone-Alpes.[ref. www.inrialpes.fr/movi/people/Mikolajczyk/Affine]                                                      
Options:
[...]
```

Comment: just another questions, how did you notice it? I'm new to linux,

Comment: @soon This is basic file system permission and Bash. You would have run into the same with a basic script and trying to execute it.